# Convert HMAC Hash from Python to PHP

Tags: python, php, hmac

Im trying to convert a Python script to PHP and I have trouble getting the same hmac hash values (hmac_signature).

Python script:

```
import hashlib
import hmac
import json
#Pre shared secret key
secret = "cd01985/813hip914Vnn04&1#11ai761"
#The message I will send
message = {"user_id": "Frank", "query": "Dog"}
#Output message: {'user_id': 'Frank', 'query': 'Dog'}
#Encode the secret using UTF-8
secret_encoded = secret.encode('utf-8')
#Output secret_encoded: b'cd01985/813hip914Vnn04&1#11ai761'
#Dump dict to string and encode using UTF-8
message_encoded = json.dumps(message).encode('utf-8')
#Output messag_encoded: ab742454c0158c3ec8d8c9c8965381567d45bee77e6f8d9aacb2239587285f87
#Compute the HMAC hash and convert to string of hex chars
hmac = hmac.new(secret_encoded, message_encoded, hashlib.sha256)
#Output hmac: <hmac.HMAC object at 0x000001E05BE4BE50>
hmac_signature = hmac.hexdigest()
#Output hmac_signature: ab742454c0158c3ec8d8c9c8965381567d45bee77e6f8d9aacb2239587285f87
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    //Pre shared secret key
    $secret = "cd01985/813hip914Vnn04&1#11ai761";
    //The message I will send
    $message = array(
        'user_id'=>"Frank",
        'query'=>"Dog"                              
    );
    //Output $message: Array ( [user_id] => Frank [query] => Dog )
    //Encode the secret using UTF-8
    $secret_encoded = utf8_encode($secret);
    //Output $secret_encoded: cd01985/813hip914Vnn04&1#11ai761
    //Dump dict to string and encode using UTF-8
    $message_encoded = json_encode($message);
    //Output $message_encoded: {"user_id":"Frank","query":"Dog"}
    $message_encoded = utf8_encode($message_encoded);
    //Output $message_encoded: {"user_id":"Frank","query":"Dog"}
    //Compute the HMAC hash and convert to string of hex chars
    $hmac_signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $message_encoded, $secret_encoded, false);
    //Output $hmac_signature: e4fd77b03cd58b174c3f6f0ad52a484386280289127f5fa7251df1686c3fb582
?>
```

Do anyone know why im getting different hash?

Edit1: What is json.dumps(message) converted into PHP, json_encode($message) dont give me same output?

Comment: I don't know if this matters but in PHP you use the original secret for the hash instead of the encoded one. Also you should compare the JSON data which may differ in additional spaces or similar things.

Comment: well, I use the original $secret. I have tried the $secret_encoded. But it's the same. The $message_encoded does not have the same output as in the Python-script. So what is json.dumps(message) actually doing in Python, and how to convert it to PHP? Clearly json_encode() is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and `message_encoded` in Python returns `b'{"query": "Dog", "user_id": "Frank"}'` for me.

The difference to PHP are the spaces which can be avoided in Python with

```
message_encoded = json.dumps(message, separators=(",", ":")).encode('utf-8')
```

Then the resulting `hmac_signature` is the same as in PHP.

Be aware that you have to use Python 3.7 or newer to ensure that the order of keys in the `dict` stays the same as given in the `dict` literal.

Comment: Ok thanks. I cannot touch the Python script. The PHP needs to match the Python script.
I tried this but it wont give me the same hmac_signature:

 $secr = "b'cd01985/813hip914Vnn04&1#11ai761'";
 $secr = utf8_encode($secr);
 $msg = "{'user_id': 'Frank', 'query': 'Dog'}";
 $msg = utf8_encode($msg);
 //Output $message_encoded: {"user_id":"Frank","query":"Dog"}
 //Compute the HMAC hash and convert to string of hex chars 
 $hmac_signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $msg, $secr, false);

Comment: b'{'user_id': 'Frank', 'query': 'Dog'}'f49bbd2501b141b87ee608875816cc4214bf403080ec7ebb00947d0d3f8b8a1b

Comment: b'{"user_id": "Frank", "query": "Dog"}'341b81b3e33b90dc1c29405d1b24f62135daf3d3d6384d108234bd8ddde11389

Comment: {'user_id': 'Frank', 'query': 'Dog'}ac2b5249a7bc26032ee6f0103c193eb44a2eb0dd8fcc2c6b831c6b1058f43490